# Movesense: how to determine wbcmd port on Windows 10

Tags: movesense

I have a movesense device with the programming jig.

I can connect to the jig using j-link, I can program/firmware update the device, but I can-not connect to the device using "wbcmd". Keeps coming up with "No device connected"

The programming jig is listed in device manager as USB device "J-link driver" but does not have a corresponding COM port.

What is the connection I put in "port" settings in the following command:-
wbcmd --port xxxx --path /Info --op GET

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the J-Link and run SEGGER J-Link Configuration tool, select your probe and enable Virtual COM-Port.
Unplug and reconnect the J-Link, the COM port should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The COM port of Movesense jig is completely separate from the SEGGER (in fact you don't need to have SEGGER connected to use it). The easiest way to get the COM port number is to open the Windows "Device Manager" and open the "Ports" sub tree. The "Ports" is not visible if there are no COM/LPT ports in the system:

[image: Ports in Device Manager]

To access the sensor over COM-port the UART must be swithced on (it's off by default since it uses over 1 mA of current). That can be done using Android version of Movesense Showcase App (wrench icon in top-right corner). Sensor needs to be reset/power cycled for UART setting to take effect.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense*